# Create HTML text in an HTML form and open up the text in a Javascript alert box

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to coding and need to create HTML text in an HTML form on a page and open up the text in a Javascript alert box. I've tried various code to no success. Here is what I've come up with so far which does not create a pop up alert box:

**Here is the HTML and the JS:**

```js
Function myfunction1()
{
  Let myfun1 = document.getElementById('sec1-input').value;
  Alert(myfun1);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sec1-input"><strong>Enter Alert Text: </strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sec1-input">
</div>
<button id="sec1-btn1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Alert Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what do you want, but I'll show you how to make an alert window exactly as you're asking. 
First of all you must consider several mistakes that you are making. JavaScript does not recognize the word Function because it is capitalized. The function keyword must be lowercase.

Here I leave you a referring link with JavaScript reserved words: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

On the other hand, I see that you are not using the **form** tag, which leads to two problems: technical and semantic. Here I leave you another link with reference to forms: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

Finally, to achieve what you want you need to work with events, especially with the click event. Here I will leave you a [reference link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp) and the solution you want:

```js
let button = document.querySelector('#sec1-btn1');
    

    button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        let val = document.querySelector('#sec1-input').value;
        alert(val);
    });
```

```html
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sec1-input"><strong>Enter Alert Text: </strong></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sec1-input" />
      </div>
      <button id="sec1-btn1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
        Alert Me!
      </button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will do as you suggest. Again, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to select my question ;)

Comment: Done! Thanks, Diesan.

Answer (score 0):

> **javaScript is case sensitive**

```js
function myfunction1()
{
  let myfun1 = document.getElementById('sec1-input').value;
  alert(myfun1);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sec1-label"><strong>Enter Alert Text: </strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sec1-input">
</div>
<button id="sec1-btn1" type="button" onClick="myfunction1()" class="btn btn-primary">Alert Me!</button>
```

**also IDs of elements should not be the same , to assign same selector , use class and you also need to give your function to your element's event listener**

Comment: Very good point, I totally forgot about how case-sensitive it is, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have not called the function anywhere. For it to work you need to use a listener.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sec1-input"><strong>Enter Alert Text: </strong></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sec1-input">
</div>
<button onclick="myfunction1()" id="sec1-btn1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Alert Me!</button> 
<script>
function myfunction1() {
  let myfun1 = document.getElementById('sec1-input').value;
  alert(myfun1)
}
</script>
```

I added the `onClick` listener to `button` and now it works.

Comment: Another thing I need to remember, the listener for the button, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not start javascript functions like **alert** with capital letters.
2. Put this piece of code instead of your button:

`<button id="sec1-btn1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myfunction1()">Alert Me!</button>`

Comment: Good point, thanks. I'm learning and so far it's hard but it will get easier.